# Javascript WYSIWYG that ignores PHP Code with Bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, tinymce

I'm adding an *.php editor to a CMS similar to as is done in Drupal's node editor. Currently, I have a selectbox with the values WYSIWYG and PHP Code. If WYSIWYG is selected then code inside the text area will be parsed with something like Tinymce (I've read other answers and found markitup.jaysalvat.com but that seemed WYSIWYG less). Whatever the javascript editor, I'd like (or will be building) a bootstrap front end to allow col, rows, btn, etc.

If PHP Code is selected then the raw PHP code will be shown and editable. I played around with this a little the other day using htmlspecialchars_encode and htmlspecialchars_decode with $_POST and everything seems fine when using PHP Code editor.

However, when I used Tinymce it wrapped all my PHP in paragraph tags, etc. Is anyone aware of a addon or alternative WYSIWYG javascript script that can parse HTML code without messing up PHP code, preferably, but NOT necessarily with builtin Bootstap3 components?

If there is something open source already out there already, it could save me from developing the whole thing from scratch.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just found: https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/dingus/ , which is close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your TinyMCE configuration:

```
protect: [
    /<\?php.*?\?>/g // Protect php code
],
```

Comment: That didn't work, but it pointed me in the right direction... should be "protect: [
     /<\?php.*?\?>/g 
 ]" [https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#example] - please update your answer. I'll select solved. Thank you

Comment: Edited per your request.